# My mdns address myhost.local mistakenly bound to Docker virtual network, not my wifi network

Tags: networking, docker, jupyter, mdns

TL;DR: How can I get `myhost.local` to resolve to my wifi interface rather than the Docker virtual network?

My desktop system's hostname is "myhost" (from `/etc/hostname` etc), running Ubuntu 18.04.
The `ip a` command tells me that my wifi ip address is `192.168.0.6`, and my rarely-used docker-network ip address is `172.17.0.1`.

I like to use mdns/Avahi to access my desktop, via "myhost.local", e.g. when connecting to local jupyter notebooks from other hosts on my home LAN.

For some reason, mdns is assigning two addresses to `myhost.local`:

```
$ host myhost.local
myhost.local has address 192.168.0.6
myhost.local has address 172.17.0.1
myhost.local has IPv6 address fe80::46da:e48:c3c0:112
```

Jupyter notebook is running with `ip=192.168.0.6`

When I `ping myhost.local`, or connect to `http://myhost.local:8888/` it worked a few months ago, but now it tries the 172.17.0.1 address, which doesn't work for jupyter.

This seems related to the unanswered question at the Docker Community Forum: [Docker network interface interferes with mDNS address](https://forums.docker.com/t/docker-network-interface-interferes-with-mdns-address/43337).

*Update*: to answer a question, this is the hosts file. I think it comes from the default way that Ubuntu sets up the hosts file, so `localhost` is not actually the same as `myhost`, but I might have tweaked it.

```
$ cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       myhost
```

*Bonus Update*

`user10489` correctly notes that other hosts will resolve `myhost.local` via mdns just fine. And my underlying problem was that I wanted to know what ip address to configure in my `jupyter notebook` to make it available over my wireless LAN. It's just that we don't see an easy way to use mdns on the *local* machine to get that answer.

The resolution to that *underlying* problem is this, to just figure out which ip address I have on a given interface (here illustrated with Ubuntu's awkwardly-named first wireless network name):

```
dev=wlp3s0
ip=$(ip -br -o a show $dev | (read interface status ip ip6; echo ${ip%/*}))
jupyter notebook --no-browser --ip=$ip
```

Comment: Can you provide what `/etc/hosts` contain?

Comment: Before this problem solved, you can use `http://localhost:8888` to access jupyter.

Comment: @emoji Given the `/etc/hosts` file (default I think with Ubuntu), `localhost` wouldn't work, but `http://127.0.1.1:8888` does, as does `http://192.168.0.6:8888` in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple name resolution mechanisms active here by default:

- /etc/hosts
- mdns
- dns

This is the default order, and mdns usually tries to resolve *.local

But also consider that this is the case separately for two machines -- the local and the remote machine.

So, if you want myhost.local to resolve to a specific interface without disabling mdns on other interfaces, you should be able to just put an override in /etc/hosts.  However, this only affects the local machine.

Remote machines will resolve myhost.local with whatever mdns broadcasts they hear.  So if they are on your docker network, and your lan (as your local machine would be), they would get all those addresses from mdns.  If they're only on one of those networks, they should see only the address that corresponds to that network.

So perhaps the solution is not to change configuration, but change what host you are using to ask the question.

Comment: This is helpful - thanks. So backing up, I want to give an `ip=` argument to `jupyter notebook` so that the notebook is available on my wireless LAN, but not to docker or any other networks. Is there a way to query for the mdns address (`myhost.local`) which sits on a given interface (in my case, `wlp3s0`)?  I also know I could specify `ip=0.0.0.0` to open it up to all interfaces, but that's more than I want.

Comment: The connection is based on IP not on hostname.  So if you want a specific interface, use a hostname that is in /etc/hosts associated with the corresponding ip address.  Don't mess with myhost.local, there's no reason to use that name to bind the listening socket.

Comment: Thanks for leading me to the right understanding. I added a Bonus Update to the question to explain how I can set the proper args to `jupyter` without having to put something new in my hosts file.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the man page for the avahi daemon conf file (/etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf) it looks like you can specify interfaces that you explicitly want to deny:

> deny-interfaces= Set a comma seperated list of network interfaces that should be ignored by avahi-daemon. Other not specified interfaces will be used, unless allow-interfaces is set. This option takes precedence over deny-interfaces.

So maybe try adding the line "deny-interfaces=docker0" to that file (always backup the original!), and then reloading with "avahi-daemon --reload". Change "docker0" to whatever your docker interface is called, though I think that's the default.

https://linux.die.net/man/5/avahi-daemon.conf

http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/avahi-daemon.8.html

Comment: Interesting - thanks. But would this disable any use of mdns by docker? That might break things. I want to just control which interface `myhost.local` resolves to.

Comment: Hmmm - I tried that, but the `host` command still shows my host on both the docker0 network along with the `wlp3s0` (eth0) network. I also note that at least on Ubuntu 18.04, it seems that avahi-daemon automatically reloads. /var/log/syslog says: `avahi-daemon[1528]: Files changed, reloading.`